# Apache Ambari not starting in hortonworks sandbox

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am playing with [hortonworks sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/learning-the-ropes-of-the-hortonworks-sandbox/), but I am not able to get Apache Ambari to work.

[image]

As you can see, when accessing the welcome page of the Hortonworks sandbox, I get a message saying:

*Service disabled by default. To enable the service you need to log in as an ambari admin.
The ambari admin password can be set by ssh'ing into the vm as root as mentioned in the section "Secure Shell (SSH) Client". Once logged in as root user, execute ambari-admin-password-reset and follow the prompt*

I did that but still, when I access the link: 127.0.0.1:8080 it's not working. I checked that the ambari-server is running:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# service ambari-server status
Using python  /usr/bin/python2
Ambari-server status
Ambari Server running
Found Ambari Server PID: 1497 at: /var/run/ambari-server/ambari-server.pid
```

I checked within the Hortonworks sandbox to confirm that Ambari Server is listening to port number 8080

```
[root@sandbox ~]# netstat -anop | grep 8080 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6320/java           off (0.00/0/0)
[root@sandbox ~]# 
[root@sandbox ~]# 
[root@sandbox ~]# ps aux | grep 6320
root      6320  9.0  4.9 4596612 398396 pts/0  Sl   05:28   3:43 /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java -server -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/ambari-server/conf/krb5JAASLogin.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/ambari-server/conf/krb5JAASLogin.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -cp /etc/ambari-server/conf:/usr/lib/ambari-server/*:/usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc.jar org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariServer
root      8750  0.0  0.0   8452   908 pts/0    S+   06:09   0:00 grep 6320
[root@sandbox ~]#
```

The iptables firewall is not running:

```
#service iptables status 
iptables: Firewall is not running.
```

The port forwarding from Guest to Host is set right

[image]

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

​I set the Guest IP address in the port forwarding settings and restarted the VM, now it's working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if the firewall in your sandbox is preventing it.

`[..]# service iptables status`

And then try accessing it after stopping iptables.

`[..]# service iptables stop`

If that too doesn't help, do check the port-forwarding settings of your Virtual Box (I assume you using Virtual Box).

Comment: Thanks, I checked that but it doesn't seem to be the cause.

Comment: I see. So, when you access http://localhost:8080 from host, does it result into 404 or simply takes forever to load or any other error message? Also from the browser see if you can access other services like (http://localhost:4200, web ssh or Zeppelin etc.)

Comment: I can access web ssh and Zeppelin, but when trying to access the 8080 (apache ambari) I get connection refused error #telnet 127.0.0.1 8080

Trying 127.0.0.1... telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: I guess you have static IP for your guest system.

Answer (score 0):

I imported horton sandbox into Vmware player. Now how should I assign host ip address and port number(8080) Apache Ambari

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the ambari's admin password; it is:

```
User: admin
Pass: 4o12t0n
```